# share a directory between a docker pgadmin container and windows10

Tags: docker, pgadmin

From within my docker pgadmin container, I want to access a postgresql backup file located in my windows10 OS.
So I'm trying to set up a shared directory.
Running this command works fine. Directory is linked to the container.

```
docker run --name=windows10 -d -v C:\Users\johndoe:/windows10 -p 5554:80 dpage/pgadmin4 -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=john@doe.com -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=whatever
```

However, the directory won't mount because it's giving this error log on startup:

```
You need to specify PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL and PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD environment variables
```

What is this sorcery??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the environment variables to before the image name

```
docker run --name=windows10 -d -v C:\Users\johndoe:/windows10 -p 5554:80  -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=john@doe.com -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=whatever dpage/pgadmin4
```

`-e` is an option and must be specified between `run` and `IMAGE` (see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

Comment: Thanks.  Here's a working example (for others)   docker run -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=john@doe.com -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin   --name "shared" -d -v ~/some/linux/directory dpage/pgadmin4